# Rsync - regex for partial folder sync (folder starting with A to M)

Tags: rsync, directory, partial

I'm new to stackoverflow and hope i do everything right.

Can anybody help me? I have a raid volume that I would like backup/sync to two other drives. The two other drives are in sum the same size than the raid volume...
But how can I tell rsync to sync only the (root)folders starting with A to M to the first drive and N-Z to the second drive? (including all the subdirectorys, and files). My regex knowledge is nearly zero.

And no I dont want to make a raid volume out of the two drives.

Or is there an option in rsync to sync to two drives (if first is full, use second..)?

Thanks for your Ideas and help in advance.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you have attempted doing what you say above?

Comment: till now I only tried to use something like: `--exclude="- [0-M]*/" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following for the 1st

`--exclude "/[N-Z]*/**"`

and following for the 2nd

```
--exclude "/[A-M]*/**"
```

The [man](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) page would help you for creating the pattern.

Comment: Thanks alot for your fast help! May I ask another detail question? How to add another letter? for "A to Mh" and "Mi to Z"?

Comment: Perhaps combinations should do. `--include "/M[a-h]*/**" --exclude "/[M-Z]*/**"`  and `--include "/M[i-z]*/**" --exclude "/[A-M]*/**"`

Comment: Do not mix up the sequence of include/exclude. Refer the man page for details on the sequence.

Comment: a first testrun (--exclude "/[N-Z]*/**") seems to work, but it looks like the folders N-Z (without files) are listed too....

Comment: In that case use the exclude options with no trailing `/**` as `--exclude "/[N-Z]*"`. The trailing `/**` would end up matching only files at any nested level within the base directory `/[N-Z]*`.